# Can someone explain setting the timezone of a MYSQL server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, timezone

I am trying to build a system which will run on multiple locations and serve different users located in different timezones. Therefore it is very important for me, that no matter where you are located servers will handle timestamps as UTC.

So far, i've setup a MYSQL server running in a docker, where docker timezone is UTC. 
I then set curent_timestamp when inserting a row in a mysql table. When i select the time in terminal command line, it seems that timestamp is UTC timezone. 
When i select the timestamp in NodeJS, the timezone is suddenly UTC but 2 hours earlier? 
Can someone explain this?

SQL select code in node:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM notificationLog WHERE subject = ? ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT ?', [activeUser, limit]);
```

Node output

[image: Image from Node console]

Terminal output

[image: Image from terminal output]